# HighLine: Using gather and answer_or_default

Tags: ruby, highline

This is my current code for ircd configuration file generator,
I'm trying to be able to use `answer_or_default` for this, and figure out the use of `HighLine::Question#gather`

Here's the `answer_or_default`

```
a = HighLine.new($stdin, $stderr)
connect_pingfreq = a.ask("? ", Integer) do |q|
  q.default = 240
  q.in = 0..300
  # q.answer_or_default
  # gives
  # /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/highline
  # -1.7.8/lib/highline/question.rb:217:in
  # `answer_or_default': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
end
# I've used it here as
# connect_pingfreq.answer_or_default
# But then gives the error shown
# ? 
# /home/ken/git/shell-scripts/inspigen/generator.rb:48:in `conf': 
# undefined method `answer_or_default' for 240:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

When using answer_or_default inside, I'm not too sure on how to give it its 'answer_string' the documentation says it wants.

And then 240 is the answer given but I can't exactly do anything with.

I'd also like to learn the use of `HighLine::Question#gather` using this piece of code. Considering I can't quite understand the documentation for it

```
a = HighLine.new($stdin, $stderr)
a.say "Your <admin> lines.."
admin_name = a.ask "Admin Real Name? "
admin_nick = a.ask "Admin Nick? "
admin_email = a.ask("Admin Email? ") do |q|
  q.validate = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/
end
```

#gather should ask me for 3 lines, name, nick, and email

Either in a hash or array, but I believe a hash would be more easily read.

Comment: "So far I've not been successful" does not describe your problem. Please explain what's wrong with your code. Actual vs desired behaviour at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can just get the answer (or default) from the `connect_pingfreq` variable. No need to call `answer_or_default`. Like this:

```
a = HighLine.new($stdin, $stderr)
connect_pingfreq = a.ask("? ", Integer) do |q|
  q.default = 240
  q.in = 0..300
end

puts connect_pingfreq
```

This will output either the answer the user entered or the default of 240.